# Can I disassociate my GitHub login with Code Chef?

Tags: javascript, github

I was looking at the Code Chef website. It looked like a good place to practice coding in JavaScript. I logged in using my GitHub information. But, after looking at the practice exercises, I realized that I can't just code in JavaScript there. I have to use either Rhino or NodeJS. I don't know either of them. (I can't afford a computer right now. So, that limits me.)

Is there a way to disassociate my GitHub profile with Code Chef since I am not going to use it? I searched and there doesn't appear to be a way to delete one's profile.

I have completed a lot of the exercises on Edabit and did a number in Code Wars. I don't want to compete. I just want to practice by doing exercises.

I ran into this same issue at Hacker Rank. I did the first few exercises in JavaScript and then couldn't run my solution in one of them because it was using NodeJS. At least, I think it was NodeJS. (It is the "Diagonal Difference".) If there is a way I can learn to run JavaScript through NodeJS just online without my own computer, that could be an option. But, I would have to be able to do everything online.

Comment: Go to https://github.com/settings/applications

Comment: Thanks, Amy. If you put it as an answer, I will mark it as the one I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the association between GitHub and sites using your Github credentials.  Go to https://github.com/settings/applications